# iOS (Safari and Chrome) black border around div

Tags: jquery, html, ios, iphone, css

I have this `div` with no border. On the iPhone/iPad browsers it appears with a black border around. The code:

```
.progress {
position: absolute;
left: 0px;
z-index: 9999;
background: #ffffff url(img/progress.gif) center 95px no-repeat;
height: 100%;
}
```

I already tried with:

```
border: 1px solid white;
```

But to no avail. Also `transparent` brings nothing.

Screenshot: http://liebdich.biz/img/Foto.PNG

Edit: 
Actually I am not sure what is happening. Since this div appears on other cases without border. Go to http://liebdich.biz/blanc to see it live. It is the `Ajax` "loading" animation `div`. Whenever you click on a link you can see it. However if you go to http://liebdich.biz/blanc/profile and click on an image you see the same `div`, but with a border...?
Can it be, that this is in connection with the jQuery `fadeOut` of the images?

Thank you!!

Comment: Did you pull this up in iOS simulator and inspect the dom?
There is another property, Outline, that could be in use. 
Are you using a CSS reset?

Comment: You have to bring more information. Please provide the html and other css in use...I made some test in nothing pops as a black border.

Comment: @stacey.mosier No, I did not use the iOS simulator, should I give a try? I tried with `outline: 0 !important;`, to no avail. I use `normalize.css`.

Comment: @Juan Go to http://liebdich.biz/blanc/profile and click on an image. Thanks!!

Comment: @loveNoHate I have the same issue, but on links instead of divs. Only on iPhone and iPad. So, 6 years later: is there a known solution meanwhile?

Comment: @JonSnow Same issue on links. I use this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/55579041/3139120

Answer (score 0):

This was happening to me and it had to do with the meta tag allowing zoom

Apparently iOS Safari has a problem with resizing things and creates that artifact

Applying a meta tag to disable zoom solved my problem (user-scalable = no)

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

Comment: This fixed the issue for me where borders were appearing on a slider container, only in landscape though on both iPhone and iPad.

Comment: With this tag you are disallowing users to zoom, which is a bad accessibility practice. For example for people with low vision who rely on screen magnifiers.

Comment: Yeah this is a big UX no-no. Not allowing users to zoom is not the way.